# Pause works incorrectly. How to fix?

Tags: javascript

I have a code that should implement stopwatch. It works, but if I start stopwatch after pressed pause or reset button, then time is ticking too fast. How can I fix it?

Resolved.

Comment: You need to post the code in your question. The error message you avoided basically told you that.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I thought it will not fit. This is my 2nd day of learning

Comment: `clearInterval(main)` makes no sense. `main` is a function, not an interval timer returned from `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a trimmed down example of how one could store an interval id and then use it to clear the interval:

```js
let SECONDS = 0;
let intervalId;

function run() {
  intervalId = setInterval(main, 1000)
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(intervalId)
  SECONDS = 0
  update_display()
}

function update_display() {
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerText = SECONDS
}

function main() {
  SECONDS++
  update_display()
}
```

```html
    <div class="display-time">
      <span id="seconds">0</span>
    </div>

    <!-- buttons start, stop and reset -->
    <div class="button-group">
      <button id="btnRun" onclick="run()">RUN</button>
      <button id="btnPause" onclick="pause()">PAUSE</button>
      <button id="btnReset" onclick="reset()">RESET</button>
    </div>
```